how to force cv2.ellipse to draw a clockwise circular arc?
cv2.ellipse seems to have a mind of its own about which way it interprets start-and end angles.
I want to draw a circular arc from 300° to 130° in the clockwise direction, i.e. like this:

with this code:
import numpy as np
import cv2

center = (200, 200) # x,y
axes = (100, 100) # first, second
angle = 0. # clockwise, first axis, starts horizontal
for i in range( 330,130,-1):
  image = np.zeros((400, 400, 3)) # creates a black image
  image = cv2.ellipse(image, center, axes, angle, 0., 360, (0,0,255))
  image = cv2.ellipse(image, center, axes, angle, 330, i, (0,255,0))
  cv2.imshow("image", image)
  cv2.waitKey(5)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I got this instead, with the green segment being drawn counter-clockwise from  330 to 130 instead of clockwise.

The code generates the red circle first and then overlays the green arc, but it demonstrates the problem.

Did you try negative angle value?

From docs: "If startAngle is greater than endAngle, they are swapped." And since it draws clockwise, that will make it appear as if it draws anticlockwise. I guess just add 180 to angle and adjust the start/end appropriately, so that start < end.

"I guess" Did  you check your suggestion by trying it? I have spent many hours trying guesses an no joy.

You may want to reconsider your attitude. But anyway: https://i.imgur.com/sQ9sKrP.png ? angle 180, and make i go from 150 to 310...

Does this answer your question? Understanding the ellipse parameters in Open CV using Python

I checked that, and couldn't get it to draw the arc from 130 to 330 anti-clockwise, it always went clockwise using those values. The answer below, from @CristiFati made me realise I needed start angle 130, end angle -29.

Note: You should have probably mentioned that your code comes from [SO]: Understanding the ellipse parameters in Open CV using Python (@api55's answer).

Listing [OpenCV.Docs]: Drawing Functions - ellipse()

Everything is a bit complicated since the display xOy system is flipped vertically ((+∞ on) Y axis is pointing down) from what we are used to (on paper), the origin is the top left corner instead of the bottom left one (and the 1st quadrant is corresponding to the 4th).


Given a circle, and 2 points on it A and B, where each point name is also the degrees (A, B ∈ [0, 360)), there are 2 ways to move from A to B (on the circle), as there are 2 arches. Choosing which arch to take has the following implications:

How much to move (distance):

Arch 1 (let this be the shorter): D1 = abs(B - A) - as distance (even in angles) is always positive

Arch 2: D2 = 360 - D1 - the remainder of the circle



Direction to move to (CCW, CW). This translates to the angle increment being added / subtracted to / from the initial value (A). 
Here, I must also mention that moving from B to A is like moving from A to B but in the opposite direction


The 2 things I mentioned above (combined with the fact that CCW is the default direction), translate into the 2 if clauses in the modified version of your code (below). Maybe the conditions are not very obvious (that's why I tried expanding them in the commented lines - code has same effect), but I couldn't find a nicer version (yet).
Anyway, it should work for any angles and directions.
code00.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

import numpy as np
import cv2


def main(*argv):
    center = (200, 200)
    axes = (100, 100)
    angle = 0.
    start = 330
    end = 130
    cw = 0 #len(sys.argv) > 1  # @TODO cfati: ClockWise?
    if start < end:
        steps = 360 + start - end
    else:
        steps = start - end
    if cw:
        steps = 360 - steps
        cw_factor = 1
    else:
        cw_factor = -1
    """
    # The above if conditions, expanded (same effect)
    if start < end:
        if cw:
            steps = end - start
            cw_factor = 1
        else:
            steps = 360 + start - end
            cw_factor = -1
    else:
        if cw:
            steps = 360 - start + end
            cw_factor = 1
        else:
            steps = start - end
            cw_factor = -1
    """
    step = 1
    base_color = (0, 0, 255)
    active_color = (0, 255, 0)
    image = np.zeros((400, 400, 3))
    for i in range(1, steps, step):
        cv2.ellipse(image, center, axes, angle, 0, 360, base_color)
        cv2.ellipse(image, center, axes, angle, start, start + cw_factor * i, active_color)
        cv2.imshow("image", image)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    print("Close drawing window to exit...")
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)


Yes, I should have mentioned the source of the code. Lesson learned.

Many thanks. The trick I missed was providing the end_value as a negative value.
